# Changing and passing attributes of an object

Tags: python, class, object, instance-methods

How do I do this?

```
class car:
    def __init__(self, tires, color, age):
        self.tires = tires
        self.color = color
        self.age = age
    def gTires(self):
        return self.tires
    def gColor(self):
        return self.color
    def gAge(self):
        return self.age

car1 = car(3, "Red", "1996")
carTires = car1.gTires
carColor = car1.gColor
carAge = car1.gAge

print("Your car 'car1' is done. It has " + carTires + " tires, is " + carColor + " and was made year " + carAge)
print()
print("But I heard you wanted it to have four tires?")
print("No problem (right?).")

car1 = car((car1.gTires + 1), (car1.gColor), (car1.gAge))
```

And so my question is about how to use attributes, do I have to set all the variables like I do in the beginning? I mean, I don't want them to be instancemethods but it seems like they will be if I don't set them. Also, at the last line I want to change the value of the number of tires car1 has, I don't want to change all the other attributes. Is there any way to do that without setting all the other attributes too?

Sorry if that didn't make sense, ask me if you find it hard to understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set an instance attribute at the moment it's created; you can set it more or less whenever you want, just by saying `self.foo = bar`. You can do it within a function of the class instance, or in a different function, or just out in your main code. You don't even need to declare it before you assign it; if at some point you decide that cars have a `doors` attribute, then you can just give any car instance one without any hassle. Objects are pretty flexible that way. You can change the number of tires by just saying `car1.tires = 453`.

There's no `private/public` thing or any other hassle to get in the way of you just changing an attribute. You don't need getters and setters like you would in a language like Java, because they wouldn't protect your variables anyway. You can just directly access them from anywhere (which makes the Java programmer in me a bit squeamish, but that's how Python works).

On another note, to use a class function, you need to say `car1.gTires()` instead of `car1.gTires`.

Comment: @CladClad I'm not sure that's strictly necessary to do. In the code he has, all of the `car1` functions would be evaluated before `car1` is reassigned, so I don't believe there will be any errors. More to the point, he doesn't need to create a totally new `car` object just to change the number of tires.

Comment: oh my bad I thought he wanted to create a new car with just one more tires compare to the other one, but he just wants to add one tires you are right ;) sorry

Comment: @CladClad it's no problem :)

Comment: Aha, well, I knew I should use brackets but I just wrote this a bit quickly and so I usually make tons of small errors... Anyway, thanks.